# Set the parent activity dynamically for the up-button

Tags: android

I have a search activity that can be called from two other activities. The search activity must have an up button that will return to the calling activities without losing the previous data.

So, how can I set the parent activity dynamically without losing the parent's data?

I saw some other questions on stackoverflow, but they don't guarantee that the previous data would be kept after pressing the up-button.

Comment: Do those two activities extend the same Activity? Why not saving your previous data in Preferences?

Comment: Maybe it will work, but I don't think it is designed to work this way. Google suggests to use two specific methods, but their sample doesn't help much.

Comment: You can use startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult(). Keep your logic different, depending on the type of parent Activity.